# Nothing from jQuery runs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am a total beginner executing JavaScript/jQuery, and I'm getting nothing. Here is my JS test:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

And I have no idea why it doesn't work. I can see the button, and I can click on the button. However, nothing happens when I do. My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
     <button>Y U NO</button>
</body>
```

Am I crazy?

Comment: you didn't include the jquery library

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>`

Comment: Doctype is HTML5 so no need for script type declaration

Answer (score 4):

Look at your browser's error console. It will be complaining that `$` is not defined (giving a reference error).

If you want to use jQuery, then you have to load it with its own script element first. There are instructions on [the jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

in your head include the jQuery library BEFORE all the other jquery scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js'></script>
```

Comment: Wow, this did it. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you!